# Ayuda con exception ADMA0043E, al intentar un deploy remoto con WAS7

Tags: websphere

Estoy intentando hacer un deploy remoto mediante el comando `./wsadmin.sh` y me tira la expcetion:

> WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "/opt/jenkins/jython/install.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
>   javax.management.MBeanException
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
>   com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMA0043E: /opt/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/temp/upload/app3125549264320256667.ear does not exist for installation.

Comment: Creo que las últimas líneas son bastante relevantes: `/opt/IBM/WebSphere7/AppServer/profiles/Dmgr01/config/temp/upload/app3125549264320256667.ear does not exist for installation.` ¿Es ese el nombre del fichero EAR que quieres desplegar?

Comment: No! el problema es que el WAS crea este archivo temporal y no lo encuentra mi ear se lama EAR-SNAPSHOT, y el ear este temporal si que existe!